# My laptop keyboard keeps sending random keystrokes even though I am not typing anything

Tags: laptop, keyboard

My issue is my keyboard is pretty much broken, it keeps inputting keys like Delete, TAB, Numlock, windows key, and others. This is super annoying as not only does it get in the way of doing pretty much anything, but also impacts the performance of the laptop as well. For now I have disabled most keys that it presses with a program called MapKeyboard, but that also blocks input from my USB keyboard, and some of the keys I'd like to keep because I need to use them.. like the windows key, TAB and delete. My goal is to get the laptop keyboard to stop all input, essentially disabling it. When previously searching for an answer I came across this : http://prntscr.com/bd8v22 and http://prntscr.com/bd8wxu
However when I tried both options(uninstalling the driver and preventing reinstall or installing invalid driver), I was unable to boot the machine, as it would BSOD me every boot, even in safe mode. I was left with no option but to do a fresh windows install. I noticed that the fresh install did not have the keyboard issues, but as soon as Windows Update ran, the issues came back. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling every possible driver, and I'm quite frankly out of ideas. My laptop is an Acer Aspire V3-772G. Was hoping someone had a solution. All I want to do is block all input from the built-in laptop keyboard without it affecting an USB keyboard.

Comment: How old is your laptop? Dirt and dusty? Liquid exposure? I ask because it sound like sticky keys or shorting. Or a bad keyboard if it's old. Are you the first and only owner? Too many reasons it could be.

Comment: yes, it's that exactly, what I'm looking for is a way to disable the keyboard though...

Comment: I am using an external one, the problem is what is written in the title.

Comment: Maybe remove the connection from the keyboard. With a little research I think you'd be able to open it up and remove the correct connection. Maybe even a peek inside will be obvious once you look at it. It's a machine after all, not just software, it has wires and routes and connections all over the place.

Comment: I have a similar problem, but even after physically removing the laptop keyboard (which includes the keyboard chip) and using a remote keyboard the issue still occurs.  I still think it's a hardware problem, but I can't figure out what it is.